# How to set recovery interval on message driven inbound adapter in java dsl?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Hey i didn't find any method on my `Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter` to assign the `recovery-interval` attribute from the xml. I do see the method on `JmsMessageChannelSpec`, but i have no idea how to actually get hold of that object. The only method that seems to be returning it is `Jms.channel` and i'm not even sure what it does. Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

Here's the config:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow primaryControlInitiationListenerFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms
                .messageDriverChannelAdapter(context.getBean("connection" + primaryConnection, ConnectionFactory.class))
                .autoStartup(false)
                .destination(queueName)
                .configureListenerContainer(listenerContainerSpec())
                .id(id + "PrimaryIn")
                .get())
            .channel("controlIdEnrichmentChannel")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public Consumer<JmsListenerContainerSpec<DefaultMessageListenerContainer>> listenerContainerSpec() {
    return new Consumer<JmsListenerContainerSpec<DefaultMessageListenerContainer>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(JmsListenerContainerSpec<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> spec) {
            spec.get().setRecoveryInterval(10000);
            spec.get().setExposeListenerSession(true);
            spec.get().setConcurrentConsumers(1);
            spec.sessionTransacted(true);
            spec.destinationResolver(context.getBean(DestinationResolver.class))
                .subscriptionDurable(false);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I just found it on the the `JmsListenerContainerSpec`, but i dunno if that's it. `spec.get().setRecoveryInterval(60000)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct; the attribute (from XML) is set on an auto-generated listener container, when a `container` attribute is not supplied.

With the DSL, you need to set it on the container itself (which is what your code is doing).

Comment: Hey but it doesn't seem to be working. Setting it to like 60 seconds is supposed to make it wait for that interval before trying to connect to the queue again on failure right? Whatever I set the interval to, it keeps giving me the error every second or so.

Comment: Show your actual config. Edit the question don't post in a comment.

Comment: I dunno if i should chain the methods on the `get()` somehow, but most of them seem to be returning void.

Comment: It's not immediately clear why it's not working, but the dsl was not really designed to keep calling `get()` on a spec (although it won't hurt in this case). It's probably much simpler (and easier to understand) if you use `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(container())...` and simply wire up a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` `@Bean` called `container()`.

Comment: I just looked with the debugger with your configuration and the container correctly gets the 10 second recovery interval.